# Why Crashlytics is not logging?

Tags: swift, firebase, crashlytics

I am using Crashlytics to log errors and when I try to test it like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
   crashlytics().log('test');
}
```

however, no logs are sent! Nonetheless, when I use `Crashlytics.crash()` it works, it logs the error which I can see in the firebase console Crashlytics dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

These logs are sent as part of the crash report and not individually.
In the dashboard when you open a crash, you will see them in the "Logs" tab. Check this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=ios#add-logs